# gulp : build several dist for website, each with own custom js

Tags: gulp

I'm currently developing a small website, used a bootstrap template that includes gulp which I am fairly new to.
The gulpfile already has a build function to build a dist directory for the final website.

The trick is that I want to build several websites, that will vary by the contents of a javascript file I want to load on some pages, I consequently have 6 of these javascript files ready.

I figured out the gulp part on the html files that works ok :

```
    @@if (context.test == 1) {
      @@include("partials/scripts_shop_1.html")
    }
    @@if (context.test == 2) {
      @@include("partials/scripts_shop_2.html")
    }
    and so on...
```

My gulp file looks as such

```
gulp.task('copy:all', function() {
  return gulp
    .src([
      paths.src.base.files,
      '!' + paths.src.partials.dir,
      '!' + paths.src.partials.files,
      '!' + paths.src.scss.dir,
      '!' + paths.src.scss.files,
      '!' + paths.src.tmp.dir,
      '!' + paths.src.tmp.files,
      '!' + paths.src.js.dir,
      '!' + paths.src.js.files,
      '!' + paths.src.css.dir,
      '!' + paths.src.css.files,
      '!' + paths.src.html.files
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.base.dir));
});

gulp.task('copy:libs', function() {
  return gulp.src(npmdist(), {
    base: paths.base.node.dir
  }).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.libs.dir));
});
gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp
    .src([paths.src.html.files, '!' + paths.src.tmp.files, '!' + paths.src.partials.files])
    .pipe(
      fileinclude({
        prefix: '@@',
        basepath: '@file',
        indent: true,
        context: {'test': 1}
      })
    )
    .pipe(replace(/href="(.{0,10})node_modules/g, 'href="$1assets/libs'))
    .pipe(replace(/src="(.{0,10})node_modules/g, 'src="$1assets/libs'))
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(cached())
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.css', cleancss()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.base.dir));
});

gulp.task(
  'build',
  gulp.series(
    gulp.parallel('clean:tmp', 'clean:dist', 'copy:all', 'copy:libs'),
    'scss',
    'html'
  )
);
```

You can see the test parameter that allows me to tell which version of the script I want to load in the html file.

What I would like to do is to be able to have a gulp task that builds all 6 websites as once, and so to be able to pass a parameter in the html function and run it in a loop. I have the same thing to do with the copy function to chose different directories but I assume it will be the same process to follow.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edward

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I ran into problems regarding gulp caching some assets from first website that had to change on others. Using gulp options to disable caching led to other issues.

The solution I found was not to generate all sites within the same gulp file but use parameters as explained in [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/pass-parameters-gulp-tasks/) article. I understand this is not recommended but it works for me here.